# What is the proper way to use multiple layouts in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I need to use multiple layouts in my project. I searched for a tutorial but there are so many different ways and couldn't find a working example.

Here is my App.js below. How can I add the second layout for Login page?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { FetchData } from './components/FetchData';
import { Counter } from './components/Counter';
import { Urun } from './components/Urun';
import { Sepet } from './components/Sepet';
import { Urunler } from './components/Urunler';

export default class App extends Component {
    displayName = App.name

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
                <Route path='/fetchdata' component={FetchData} />
                <Route path='/Urun' component={Urun} />
                <Route path='/Sepet' component={Sepet} />
                <Route path='/Urunler' component={Urunler} />      
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```

**THIS IS THE ANSWER FROM @Quentin**

Thanks to @Quentin, he didnt give me the fish but helped me catch the fish.

This is the App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { FetchData } from './components/FetchData';
import { Counter } from './components/Counter';
import { Urun } from './components/Urun';
import { Sepet } from './components/Sepet';
import { Urunler } from './components/Urunler';
import { Giris } from './components/Giris';
import { Kayit } from './components/Kayit';

export default class App extends Component {
    displayName = App.name

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
                <Route path='/fetchdata' component={FetchData} />
                <Route path='/Urun' component={Urun} />
                <Route path='/Sepet' component={Sepet} />
                <Route path='/Urunler' component={Urunler} />
                <Route path='/Giris' component={Giris} />
                <Route path='/Kayit' component={Kayit} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Layout } from './Layout';

export class Home extends Component {
    displayName = Home.name

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <div>
                    ......
                </div>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever your `Layout` component is, put it inside the route components you want to use it in instead of around all the routes (including those where you don't want to use it).

Comment: I dont have a route component. I guess I need to add a route component first.

Comment: @ArifYILMAZ — Yes you do. See where **six** times you have a `<Route>` and you say `component={SOMETHING}`? Those SOMETHINGs are route components.

Comment: Would you please give an example of your first answer above? I am a bit confused

Comment: Edit `Home` so that it wraps whatever its render method returns in `<Layout>`. Also do the same to `Counter`. and so on.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but It is not very clear to me yet. I am still working on it. When you said "Edit Home", do you mean "Home.js" or the line in the App.js

Comment: Home.js. The line in App.js doesn't have a render method that belongs to the Home component.

Answer (score 2):

Each route has to be rendered in the target layout.
for e.g https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/multiple-layout-in-react-with-react-router-v4/

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to clarify more between terms `layout` and `component`.
I assume you asking how to add component?

You would need first create the file ./components/Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Login</p>
        )
    }
}
```

Then use the following to import:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { FetchData } from './components/FetchData';
import { Counter } from './components/Counter';
import { Urun } from './components/Urun';
import { Sepet } from './components/Sepet';
import { Urunler } from './components/Urunler';
// HERE import your component
import { Login } from './components/Login';

export default class App extends Component {
    displayName = App.name

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
                <Route path='/fetchdata' component={FetchData} />
                <Route path='/Urun' component={Urun} />
                <Route path='/Sepet' component={Sepet} />
                <Route path='/Urunler' component={Urunler} /> 
                // HERE make it into a route path
                <Route path='/login' component={Login} />      
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```